# Filling a column in a csv file with a list in R? (with a twist)

Tags: r, list, csv

I have a list of 6 with 40 entries in each list. My goal is to add a column in a csv file under the header "results" so basically under csv$results. The special thing here is that I would like to put every entry of my list in csv$results 3 times before going to the next entry in my list. So that in the end I will have for example:

```
csv$results
1.3
1.3
1.3
2.8
2.8
2.8
2.4
2.4
2.4
```

etc

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ind = rep(1:40, each=3)
csv$results = csv$results[ind]
```